# JSF filter not executed

Tags: jsf, servlet-filters

```
@WebFilter(filterName = "loginFilter",  value = { "/faces/kosz.xhtml" } , dispatcherTypes = { DispatcherType.FORWARD, DispatcherType.ERROR, DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.INCLUDE }  )
public class loginFilter implements Filter {    
    public loginFilter(){
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
                         FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException{
        HttpServletRequest req = ( HttpServletRequest ) request;
        userSession auth = ( userSession ) req.getSession().getAttribute("user");
        if ( auth != null && auth.isLogged() ) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
             HttpServletResponse res = ( HttpServletResponse ) response;
            res.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + "/login.xhtml");
        }
        else {
            HttpServletResponse res = ( HttpServletResponse ) response;
            res.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + "/login.xhtml");
        }
      }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException
      {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
      }

    @Override
    public void destroy()
      {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
      }
/**
 * Return the filter configuration object for this filter.
}
```

The problem is that the filter doesn't execute. THe URL is `localhost:8080/PP2/faces/kosz.xhtml` . What  would be the proper way to do this?
I have no entry in my web.xml, it's all based on Annotations.

Comment: Where did you get the filter template from? All those `UnsupportedOperationException`s are utterly wrong. I however recall having seen this a few times before. Perhaps you found it somewhere in a website or a book. If so, which one?

Comment: Really? Wow. It thus not only generates servlets whose `doPost()` and `doGet()` delegate to very same `processRequest()` method which is utterly wrong, but it also generates broken filters like that?

Comment: Well its default code snippet when you want netbeans to implement all interface methods. it probably can be changed in NB options, but its default.

Comment: In Eclipse, I just do rightclick package, *New*, *Filter*, specify classname and that's it.

Comment: It is very stupid from them. Like they want to just put the code which will cause problems, and hide that in throwing `RuntimeException` just to be shore you will not see any compiler errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You throw exceptions in `init()` and `destroy()` methods of filter. If you don't want to do anything in `init()` or `destroy()`, just leave body of method empty. In this case your filter is not successfully initialized at all.

Comment: Haha, that was clever :D. Thank you.